# Python kivy md Navigation Bar placement?

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to restructure the kivymd project file but I am not able to place the navigation bar at the place at which it is normally. I cannot see why this is happening (see pictures and code below).

This is how it looks like
[image]
[image]

and this is how it should look like
[image]
[image]

I am using the three files app.py, app.kv and labels.py (for injecting labels from a *.py file).

```
# app.kv
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

import kivy.app
from kivy.lang import Builder
from application.kivymd.list import BaseListItem
from application.kivymd.material_resources import DEVICE_TYPE
from application.kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer, NavigationDrawerHeaderBase
from application.kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

    # User defined imports
    from kivy.core.window import Window

    Window.fullscreen = "auto"


    class HackedDemoNavDrawer(MDNavigationDrawer):
        # DO NOT USE
        def add_widget(self, widget, index=0):
            if issubclass(widget.__class__, BaseListItem):
                self._list.add_widget(widget, index)
                if len(self._list.children) == 1:
                    widget._active = True
                    self.active_item = widget
                # widget.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.panel.toggle_state())
                widget.bind(on_release=lambda x: x._set_active(True, list=self))
            elif issubclass(widget.__class__, NavigationDrawerHeaderBase):
                self._header_container.add_widget(widget)
            else:
                super(MDNavigationDrawer, self).add_widget(widget, index)


    class MainApp(kivy.app.App):
        theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        title = "Application"

        def build(self):
            main_widget = Builder.load_file(
                os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./app.kv")
            )
            # self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

            main_widget.ids.text_field_error.bind(
                on_text_validate=self.set_error_message,
                on_focus=self.set_error_message)
            self.bottom_navigation_remove_mobile(main_widget)
            return main_widget

        def bottom_navigation_remove_mobile(self, widget):
            # Removes some items from bottom-navigation demo when on mobile
            if DEVICE_TYPE == 'mobile':
                widget.ids.bottom_navigation_demo.remove_widget(widget.ids.bottom_navigation_desktop_2)
            if DEVICE_TYPE == 'mobile' or DEVICE_TYPE == 'tablet':
                widget.ids.bottom_navigation_demo.remove_widget(widget.ids.bottom_navigation_desktop_1)

        def set_error_message(self, *args):
            if len(self.root.ids.text_field_error.text) == 2:
                self.root.ids.text_field_error.error = True
            else:
                self.root.ids.text_field_error.error = False

        def on_pause(self):
            return True

        def on_stop(self):
            pass


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MainApp().run()
```

This is the app.kv file which is injected into the app.py file

```
# app.kv
#:import Toolbar application.kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import MDNavigationDrawer application.kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout application.kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerDivider application.kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerDivider
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar application.kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar
#:import NavigationDrawerSubheader application.kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerSubheader
#:import MDCheckbox application.kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDCheckbox
#:import MDSwitch application.kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDSwitch
#:import MDTextField application.kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:import MDThemePicker application.kivymd.theme_picker.MDThemePicker
#:import labels application.labels

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        NavigationDrawerToolbar:
            title: labels.NAVIGATION
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.DASHBOARD
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'dashboard'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.SYSTEM_INSPECTOR
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'system_inspector'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.SYSTEM_PARAMETERS
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'system_parameters'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        halign: "center"
        Toolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: labels.APPLICATION_NAME
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: 'Primary'
            background_hue: '500'
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
            #right_action_items: [['dots-vertical', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        ScreenManager:
            id: scr_mngr
            Screen:
                name: 'dashboard'
                MDLabel:
                    font_style: 'Body1'
                    theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                    text: "This is the dashboard!"
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: '250dp'
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.50, "center_y": 0.75}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_1
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_2
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDSwitch:
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(36), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    _active:        False
            Screen:
                name: 'system_inspector'
                MDLabel:
                    font_style: 'Body1'
                    theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                    text: "This is the system_inspector page!"
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: '250dp'
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.50, "center_y": 0.75}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_1
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_2
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDSwitch:
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(36), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    _active:        False
            Screen:
                name: 'system_parameters'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                            input_filter: "float"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                            input_filter: "int"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            Screen:
                name: 'textfields'
                ScrollView:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Persistent helper text"
                            helper_text: "Text is always here"
                            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        MDTextField:
                            id: text_field_error
                            hint_text: "Helper text on error (Hit Enter with two characters here)"
                            helper_text: "Two is my least favorite number"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Max text length = 10"
                            max_text_length: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "required = True"
                            required: True
                            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                        MDTextField:
                            multiline: True
                            hint_text: "Multi-line text"
                            helper_text: "Messages are also supported here"
                            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "color_mode = \'accent\'"
                            color_mode: 'accent'
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "color_mode = \'custom\'"
                            color_mode: 'custom'
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                            helper_text: "Color is defined by \'line_color_focus\' property"
                            line_color_focus: self.theme_cls.opposite_bg_normal  # This is the color used by the textfield
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "disabled = True"
                            disabled: True
            Screen:
                name: 'nav_drawer'
                HackedDemoNavDrawer:
                    # NavigationDrawerToolbar:
                    #     title: "Navigation Drawer Widgets"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
                        text: "Badge text ---->"
                        badge_text: "99+"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        active_color_type: 'accent'
                        text: "Accent active color"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        active_color_type: 'custom'
                        text: "Custom active color"
                        active_color: [1, 0, 1, 1]
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        use_active: False
                        text: "Use active = False"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        text: "Different icon"
                        icon: 'alarm'
                    NavigationDrawerDivider:
                    NavigationDrawerSubheader:
                        text: "NavigationDrawerSubheader"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        text: "NavigationDrawerDivider \/"
                    NavigationDrawerDivider:
```

Here is the labels.py file for injecting the labels into the kv file.

```
# labels.py
APPLICATION_NAME = "Application"
NAVIGATION = "Navigation"
DASHBOARD = "Dashboard"
SYSTEM_INSPECTOR = "System Inspector"
SYSTEM_PARAMETERS = "System Parameters"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

You might have a kv file with a name, `main.kv`

With KivyMD installed on my machine, and some minor changes, the KivyMD App ran fine.

## Example

### app.py

```
# app.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.list import BaseListItem
from kivymd.material_resources import DEVICE_TYPE
from kivymd.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer, NavigationDrawerHeaderBase
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

# User defined imports
from kivy.core.window import Window

# Window.fullscreen = "auto"


class HackedDemoNavDrawer(MDNavigationDrawer):
    # DO NOT USE
    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0):
        if issubclass(widget.__class__, BaseListItem):
            self._list.add_widget(widget, index)
            if len(self._list.children) == 1:
                widget._active = True
                self.active_item = widget
            # widget.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.panel.toggle_state())
            widget.bind(on_release=lambda x: x._set_active(True, list=self))
        elif issubclass(widget.__class__, NavigationDrawerHeaderBase):
            self._header_container.add_widget(widget)
        else:
            super(MDNavigationDrawer, self).add_widget(widget, index)


class MainApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = "Application"

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_file(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./app.kv")
        )
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        main_widget.ids.text_field_error.bind(
            on_text_validate=self.set_error_message,
            on_focus=self.set_error_message)
        self.bottom_navigation_remove_mobile(main_widget)
        return main_widget

    def bottom_navigation_remove_mobile(self, widget):
        # Removes some items from bottom-navigation demo when on mobile
        if DEVICE_TYPE == 'mobile':
            widget.ids.bottom_navigation_demo.remove_widget(widget.ids.bottom_navigation_desktop_2)
        if DEVICE_TYPE == 'mobile' or DEVICE_TYPE == 'tablet':
            widget.ids.bottom_navigation_demo.remove_widget(widget.ids.bottom_navigation_desktop_1)

    def set_error_message(self, *args):
        if len(self.root.ids.text_field_error.text) == 2:
            self.root.ids.text_field_error.error = True
        else:
            self.root.ids.text_field_error.error = False

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_stop(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

### labels.py

```
# labels.py
APPLICATION_NAME = "Application"
NAVIGATION = "Navigation"
DASHBOARD = "Dashboard"
SYSTEM_INSPECTOR = "System Inspector"
SYSTEM_PARAMETERS = "System Parameters"
```

### app.kv

```
# app.kv
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import MDNavigationDrawer kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerDivider kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerDivider
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar
#:import NavigationDrawerSubheader kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerSubheader
#:import MDCheckbox kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDCheckbox
#:import MDSwitch kivymd.selectioncontrols.MDSwitch
#:import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
#:import MDThemePicker kivymd.theme_picker.MDThemePicker
#:import labels labels

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        NavigationDrawerToolbar:
            title: labels.NAVIGATION
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.DASHBOARD
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'dashboard'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.SYSTEM_INSPECTOR
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'system_inspector'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: labels.SYSTEM_PARAMETERS
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'system_parameters'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        halign: "center"
        Toolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: labels.APPLICATION_NAME
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: 'Primary'
            background_hue: '500'
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
            #right_action_items: [['dots-vertical', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        ScreenManager:
            id: scr_mngr
            Screen:
                name: 'dashboard'
                MDLabel:
                    font_style: 'Body1'
                    theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                    text: "This is the dashboard!"
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: '250dp'
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.50, "center_y": 0.75}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_1
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_2
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDSwitch:
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(36), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    _active:        False
            Screen:
                name: 'system_inspector'
                MDLabel:
                    font_style: 'Body1'
                    theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                    text: "This is the system_inspector page!"
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: '250dp'
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.50, "center_y": 0.75}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_1
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.25, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDCheckbox:
                    id:            grp_chkbox_2
                    group:        'test'
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(48), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                MDSwitch:
                    size_hint:    None, None
                    size:        dp(36), dp(48)
                    pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    _active:        False
            Screen:
                name: 'system_parameters'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                            input_filter: "float"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                            input_filter: "int"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            Screen:
                name: 'textfields'
                ScrollView:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        padding: dp(48)
                        spacing: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "No helper text"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Helper text on focus"
                            helper_text: "This will disappear when you click off"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Persistent helper text"
                            helper_text: "Text is always here"
                            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        MDTextField:
                            id: text_field_error
                            hint_text: "Helper text on error (Hit Enter with two characters here)"
                            helper_text: "Two is my least favorite number"
                            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "Max text length = 10"
                            max_text_length: 10
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "required = True"
                            required: True
                            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                        MDTextField:
                            multiline: True
                            hint_text: "Multi-line text"
                            helper_text: "Messages are also supported here"
                            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "color_mode = \'accent\'"
                            color_mode: 'accent'
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "color_mode = \'custom\'"
                            color_mode: 'custom'
                            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                            helper_text: "Color is defined by \'line_color_focus\' property"
                            line_color_focus: self.theme_cls.opposite_bg_normal  # This is the color used by the textfield
                        MDTextField:
                            hint_text: "disabled = True"
                            disabled: True
            Screen:
                name: 'nav_drawer'
                HackedDemoNavDrawer:
                    # NavigationDrawerToolbar:
                    #     title: "Navigation Drawer Widgets"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
                        text: "Badge text ---->"
                        badge_text: "99+"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        active_color_type: 'accent'
                        text: "Accent active color"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        active_color_type: 'custom'
                        text: "Custom active color"
                        active_color: [1, 0, 1, 1]
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        use_active: False
                        text: "Use active = False"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        text: "Different icon"
                        icon: 'alarm'
                    NavigationDrawerDivider:
                    NavigationDrawerSubheader:
                        text: "NavigationDrawerSubheader"
                    NavigationDrawerIconButton:
                        text: "NavigationDrawerDivider \/"
                    NavigationDrawerDivider:
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]
[image: Img03]
[image: Img04]

Comment: Plus one for your help. But what have you changed?

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think there was (and still is) some confusion about the imports.

Comment: 1) In kv file, removed all references to `applications.` 2) In Python code, added import statements for KivyMD, replaced import `kivy.app` with `from kivy.app import App`, and replace `kivy.app.App` with `App`.